# Laravel - Parse Blade to Vue Component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Laravel auth scaffolding creates a layout for the rest of views.

The question is simple: How can convert this layout to vue component?

Blade file. I need to convert to Vue.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href=’https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel=”stylesheet”>
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by parsing?

Comment: Maybe i need more specific. I need to convert a blade layout into a vue component.

Comment: Create a component called `Login.vue` and put the markup from `blade` in `<template>` part of that component. Use that `<login>` component in the blade.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I will create a base vue layout. Then when page load i redirect to the login component and load base layout (importing as a *local component*). Then when redirect to other page (for example a component with drawer) i will load this component but will load the base layout too.

To help to do that i will use [Vue slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html). I see how works **[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoCbmtp1xw0)**. The video is in spanish but i think we can understands it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, this is included as of Laravel 5.7

You generate scaffolding and publish the components with:

```
composer require laravel/ui "^1.0" --dev

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

It will get you started with an example component so see how you can call that from a blade template.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-routing

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-views

Comment: But scaffolding creates base layout in php (blade). I need to use (¿or convert in vue maybe?) it in all application because has csrf and other stuff in head tag. The problem is that i need to redirect to drawer component inside a blade but vue router can't call blade files.